# Publish result for multiple test suites

Tags: testing, tcm

I need to publish the result using from .trx file using tcm command

I am able to publish using following command:

```
tcm run /publish /suiteid:1350 /configid:11 /collection:http://tfs2010 /teamproject:DreamProject /resultsfile:"C:\publish.trx" /resultowner:"Myself"
```

But this command will publish result for only one `suiteid`. I need to do this for multiple suiteid's in single command. Is that possible?